# MQTT Paho Client issue

Tags: mqtt, paho

I'm using MQTT paho for android mqtt connection for the last 15 ~ 20 days the client seems to works normally. but from last day the problem occurs.
I can successfully subscribe to messages and able to publish from the client but it won't affect the cloud data.

The subscribe and publish are working normally when I change my clientid to another value.

So my question is that does client id matter in performance issue?

Comment: Without detailed information about the cloud service you are using there is no way to answer this.

Comment: @hardillb I'm using CloudMqtt cloud

Comment: Then you probably need to contact them to ask them what's going on.